# Find a point on a parabola that's closest to another point.

Tags: calculus

Find the point on the parabola $3x^2+4x-8$ that is closest to the point $(-2,-3)$.

My plan for this problem was to use the distance formula and then that the derivative to get my answer. I'm having a little trouble along the way.

$$ d = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}.$$

Comment: Firstly, you can use the equation of the parabola, so that $y_1=3x_1^2-4x_1-8$. Secondly, you can (and should) work with the distance squared. The calculations are much easier without the square root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the closest point is at $p=(x_0,y_0)$, and set $q=(-2,-3)$. Then the tangent to the parabola at $p$ is perpendicular to $\ell$, the line through $p,q$.

Since $y'=6x+4$, the slope of the tangent is $6x_0+4$, so the slope of $\ell$ is $-\frac{1}{6x_0+4}$. Since it passes through $q$, we see the equation for $\ell$ is
$$y+3 = -\frac{x+2}{6x_0+4}$$

Combining with $y=3x^2+4x-8$ shows that $x_0$ is a root of
$$
(6x+4)(3x^2+4x-5)+(x+2)=18x^3+36x^2-13x-18=0
$$
and we end up numerically computing the roots from here.

Comment: That's a much cleverer way of doing it! +1

Comment: Thanks, just a little plane geometry

Comment: -1 I disagree. The slope of the tangent is $6x_0 + 4$, and not $6$. The equation you should have is $\frac{y+3}{x+2} = - \frac{1}{6x+4}$, which is what Jacob has (after replacing $y = 3x^2+4x-8$).

Comment: @JacobMayle Note that his equation is different from your (and has different roots too since their GCD is 1), so at least one of you is wrong.

Comment: I had logged out for the today when I realized my mistake, which is basically a typo. Thanks for catching it - it shows that people are actually reading these answers!

Comment: @CalvinLin Good catch. I checked the roots of $18x^2 + 23x - 32$ on W|A and one of them was very nearly $x$-value of the point that I got. I just chalked the difference up to a rounding error in the numerical approximation.

Comment: @pre-kidney I think we still disagree.

Comment: Yeah accidentally subtracted $x+2$ instead of added.

Apologies everyone for the two silly mistakes! I'm usually not this careless, not sure what happened today!

Comment: @pre-kidney Ok. Now our answers agree.

Comment: To recap, our solutions boil down to the same calculation - just a slightly different intuition at the start. I guess your first comment on this answer is not really accurate any more...

Comment: @pre-kidney Not as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Apologies, this whole mess was unintentional.

Answer (score 8):

$$ d = \sqrt{(x - (-2))^2 + ((3x^2+4x-8) - (-3))^2} = \sqrt{\left(x+2\right) ^2 + \left(3x^2+4x-5 \right)^2}$$

Instead of minimizing $d$, lets minimize $d^2$. It should be noted that the minimum of $d$ and $d^2$ are exactly the same as $d \geq 0$. This gets rid of the square root, thereby simplifying the problem.

$$d^2 = (x+2)^2 + (3x^2+4x-5)^2.$$

Now, we can use calculus to minimize $d^2$,

$$(d^2)' = 2(x+2) + 2(3x^2+4x-5)(6x+4) = 36x^3 + 72x^2 - 26x - 36$$

This has roots at $x \approx -2.118, -.631, .749$. We know that one of these must be the absolute minimum, so evaluate $d^2$ for each $x$-value and whichever is smallest is the $x$-value of the point on the parabola nearest to the given point. You should then plug that $x$-value into the equation for the parabola to determine the $y$-value where this occurs. I got,

> Ans: $ (-2.118, -3.014) $