# Distance between point and sine (again)

Tags: functions

There already was a question ([Distance between point and sine wave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514820/distance-between-point-and-sine-wave)), but this seems not contain the answer for me.

The formula written there is depends on x

```
x=e−bc⋅cos(cx+d)(a+b⋅sin(cx+d)−f)
```

which not provides an answer (just asks a new one question).

My definition:
We have a point (x, y) and a sine function defined by (amplitude, frequency, phase).
We need to find distance from point to nearest point on sine.

This needs for Signed Distance Field representation of bodies (I want to create helical springs and threads)

playground is here https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Md3yRH

Comment: yes this is possibe, write down the equations

Comment: I am not a strong at math, I need a help for writing and solving them. I need in a signed distace field form  to create a helical spring representation

Comment: I have not see the answer there. There is no final answer in form of useable formula.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, you are wrong, this is not possible (see the answer below)

Comment: I have added an answer to the original question describing my method of solving this problem by turning it into a "closest point on parabola" problem https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4440443/25732

Answer (score 2):

Let the sinusoid be

$$y=a\sin x$$ and the point $(u,v)$.

I have omitted the phase paremeter because by translation it can be absorbed in $u$. And I have omitted the frequency parameter, because it can be absorbed in $u,v,a$ by scaling.

Now the squared distance is

$$(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2=(x-u)^2+(a\sin x-v)^2$$ and you can obtain the extrema by canceling the derivative

$$x-u+a\cos x(a\sin x-v)=0.$$

This is a nasty nonlinear equation that you have to solve by numerical methods. Then direct minimization is also possible. But the shape of the curve is a little scary.

[image]

Notice the inequality

$$(x-u)^2+(|a|-|v|)^2\le(x-u)^2+(a\sin x-v)^2\le (x-u)^2+(|a|+|v|)^2.$$

Considering the minimum of the upper bound, you get an $x$ interval where the searched minimum is guranteed to lie by solving

$$(x-u)^2+(|a|-|v|)^2=(|a|+|v|)^2.$$

[image]

From the second derivative,

$$1+a\sin x(a\sin x-v)+a^2\cos^2x=0.$$

This is a quadratic equation in $\sin x$, which you can solve analytically. It will give you the locations of the extrema of the first derivative, hence it separates the roots. By detecting the intervals with a change of sign, you can apply regula falsi.

Combining with the previous criterion, you can be sure to find the minimum with a finite number of attempts.

Comment: Oh! Numerical methods... So, using them is the first what I thought, but I was thinking it's possible in exact form. Math is so ugly.